# Applications of the following theorem in the real world

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, permutations, computer-science

We know that every permutation can be expressed as a product of transpositions ( cycles with length 2). As a class project I'm looking for the applications of this fact in the real world; especially in computer science. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking into the subject of sorting algorithms where you compare pairs and interchange them if necessary.

Comment: @String thanks, I found many paper dealing sorting by transpositions.

Comment: But, is there any other application?

Answer (score 1):

This is more fun than "real world", but [Keeler's Theorem](https://youtu.be/8M4dUj7vZJc) is something.

Comment: +1 for linking to a clip with Futurama. That video made me laugh. :)